# sparksql: How to save hdfs files to different folder according to field name

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When I use `sparksql`, I want to save the file to a different folder according to the name of the field, because there are more than `200` fields enumerated. How can I save it gracefully? At present, the way I use it is inefficient.
As shown in the figure.
[image]

Comment: create table mytrgtable partitioned by (prefix) as select * from mysrctable

Comment: Why not use `ssb.sql("sql query").write.partitionBy("prefix").csv("outputPath")`

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I can do it in the way mentioned above. Thank you!